# Django get unique manytomany

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Word(Model):
    word = CharField()
    categories = ManyToManyField('Category')

class Category(Model):
   name = CharField()
```

What is the best way to fetch all unique list of categories?

For example, if I have

```
apple -> General, Garden
pear -> General, Garden
computer -> IT
```

I want to get the following list of lists

```
(General, Garden)
(IT, )
```

I need PostgreSQL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `GroupConcat` function like this one:

```
class GroupConcat(models.Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s%(ordering)s%(separator)s)'

    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, ordering=None, separator=',', **extra):
        super(GroupConcat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            ordering=' ORDER BY %s' % ordering if ordering is not None else '',
            separator=' SEPARATOR "%s"' % separator,
            output_field=models.CharField(),
            **extra
        )
```

Then you can do:

```
Word.objects.all().annotate(
        category_names=GroupConcat('categories__name')
    ).values_list('category_names').distinct()
```

PS. This is a MySQL solution.

Comment: I use array_agg for Postgres, but distinct doesn't work.